# How to choose design pattern for processing of input data?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a code snippet that is used to process strings of text files. The function `processFile` is called for every file in the directory

```
void processFile(const std::string& sourceFileName) {
    std::ifstream sourceFile;
    sourceFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
    try {
        sourceFile.open(sourceFileName);
        if (sourceFile.is_open()) {
            while (sourceFile.peek() != EOF) {
                std::string line;
                std::getline(sourceFile,line);
                // process line here
            }
            sourceFile.close();
        }
    }
    catch (const std::ifstream::failure& exception) {
        std::cout << "some exception text here" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "some another exception text here" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Besides files, I also need to read data from pipes and from sockets.
What design pattern can be used to abstractly open, read and close an entity? Could you please give me some examples?

Comment: Is the `// process line here` part the same for each type of input? The put it in another function that can be called from different functions handling the different input.

Comment: Also note that on POSIX systems (like Linux and macOS) pipes and sockets are all handled with descriptors, and you can use the same function to read from both.